# Regarding equivalent conditions of Frechet differentiability

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Gateaux and Frechet differentiability in a Banach space are defined as below.
[image]
Can you tell below how (ii) implies (i). The rest is easy.[image]

Comment: The equivalence of (i) and (ii) is just your given definition of Fréchet differentiability, isn't it?

Comment: In the above, what is $S_X$?

Comment: I would guess that $S_X$ is the unit sphere of $X$, i.e., $S_X = \{x \in X \mid \|x\|=1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me denote $f(x):=\|x\|$ and
the limit
$$
f'(x;h) = \lim_{t\to0} \frac1t{f(x+th)-f(x)} \quad x\in S_X,h\in X.
$$
Due to (ii), this limit exists for all such $x,t$.

First, let me show that $h\mapsto f'(x;h)$ is a linear map. Let $h\in X$, $s\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ be given. Then
$$
f'(x; sh) =  \lim_{t\to0} \frac1t{f(x+sth)-f(x)} = s \lim_{t\to0} \frac1{st}{f(x+sth)-f(x)}  = s f'(x;h).
$$
Let now $h_1,h_2$ be given. Then by convexity (or triangle inequality)
$$
\|x + \frac12t(h_1+h_2)\| \le \frac12 \|x+th_1\| + \frac12 \|x+th_2\|.
$$
Subtracting $\|x\|$ on both sides, dividing by $t>0$, passing to the limit $t\searrow0$ yields
$$
  f'(x,\frac12(h_1+h_2))\le \frac12 f'(x,h_1+h_2)+\frac12 f'(x,h_1+h_2),
$$
which implies $f'(x;h_1+h_2) \le f'(x;h_1)+f'(x;h_2)$. Replacing $h_i$ by $-h_i$ implies the reverse inequality, hence $f'(x;h_1+h_2) = f'(x;h_1)+f'(x;h_2)$.
This proves Gateaux differentiability of the norm.

The uniformity of the limit then gives the required $o$-property to obtain Frechet differentiability.